# SFDX: is there a command to retrieve an inbound change set?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

There is an SFDX command to retrieve **outbound** change sets from an org. This command works great for that:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./desiredDirectory -u <username> -p <change set name>
```

However, I tried this command to retrieve an **inbound** change set, and it doesn't work. Is there no SFDX command to retrieve an **inbound** change set?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to retrieve metadata from the closed Changeset.

You will need access to the source org to receive metadata from the changeset.

Comment: Bummer. Does that mean that if I create outbound change sets in the source org, push those changes to the target org, then refresh the source org from production ( a separate org altogether), the target org will no longer have those change sets?

Comment: You will definitely have access to the Changeset but you won’t be able to pull metadata from it just by changeset name. There is nothing stopping you from constructing package.xml manifest based on changeset manually